# AQV255GS Opto-MOSFET datasheet confusion - what's the actual max frequency?

Tags: datasheet, opto-isolator

On page 1, abs max ratings, it mentions operating conditions such as: "f = 100 Hz, Duty factor = 0.1%"
Which there, is only to specify the conditions for some other boundary, but one might think that for this, realistically occurring operating conditions would be mentioned.

Then, on page 2, bottom of the table, "Transfer characteristics", it has: "Max. switching frequency ...  5 times/s" for my part.

Is that a rather weird way to write 5 Hz, or does it mean somehting else?
5Hz would seem rather slow. While it may be fast enough to PWM-drive a heater resistor (?), I'm still surprized about:

1. the slowness (I haven't seen an opto-coupler this slow before)
2. why they'd mention a scenario with 100Hz in another place.
3. If I add the maximum turn-on + turn-off times given, with 5.5 ms it should still do 181 Hz, not 5.

What does it really mean?

[Datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/AQV255GS-Panasonic-datasheet-27889832.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a LED shining on a photocell which generates a tiny current to charge the MOSFET gate, so switching is very slow (up to 5ms).

It says it can switch 5 times/s at IL = Max., VL = Max.

I'll take IL=3A and VL=50V for AQV252G2S (first column).

The [energy dissipated in the MOSFET during switching](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt664/slyt664.pdf) depends on switching time Ts, it can be estimated by \$ Ts V I \$. The idea behind this is the MOSFET behaves as a resistor during switching, it is neither fully on nor fully off, so its Vds is the full supply voltage and its Id is the full load current.

In your case this gives an over-estimate for the following reasons:

- The datasheet gives turn-on time, but this is not equal to switching time.

Turn-on time is measured from the moment the LED is powered, but the photocell has to charge the gate capacitance up to the FET threshold voltage before it begins to conduct. During this latency the FET is turned off so it doesn't dissipate anything. The actual switching time is unknown and the datasheet doesn't specify it, but it sure will be lower than the turn-on time. Since typical turn-on time is 1.5ms and max is 5ms, for the sake of example, let's use Ts=1-4ms.

- The formula assumes an inductive load

The formula targets a buck converter, in case as soon as the FET begins to conduct, the inductor will snap the FET Vds to the full supply voltage and it will take the full inductor current, hence the V*I. However if you use this component to switch a resistive load, then current will start at zero then ramp up smoothly during the turn-on of the FET. So the actual dissipation will be much lower than estimated, and it depends on the load resistor.

Anyway, this worst case calculation gives 1-4ms * 3A * 50V = 0.15-0.6 Joules. Since it turns off much faster, I'll neglect the turn-off energy. Dissipation in watts in the MOSFET is the product of switching by times the number of times it switches per second, so in this case at the maximum frequency of 2.5 Hz this gives 0.4-1.5 Watts of dissipation which is already a lot for a SOP-6 package.

So to summarize, because it switches very slow, switching losses are huge, so they're warning you to not switch it too often.

Switching losses depend on voltage, current, and load resistor value, so they just give a worst case value.

Further in the datasheet there is a graph:

[image]

The X axis is V*I so you can use that to find the max switching frequency. This time, it's labeled in Hz, so that should clear up the confusion.

At very low load current, there is no dissipation issue, so you can switch it as fast as it will go.

Using a higher LED current causes the photocell to output more current and reduces turn-on time, and therefore switching losses, so it should be possible to use a higher switching frequency by increasing the LED current.